# Install library backtrader Python in error

Tags: python, conda, spyder

Good morning. I installed backtrader on windows via cmd prompt like this:
pip3 install backtrader

but from Spyder Anaconda when I write import backtrader as bt, it returns me:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backtrader'
can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: Hello Mario! What is your script name?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read our [guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Is Spyder using the correct Conda environment? Was the library installed in the right environment?

Answer (score 1):

try to run the following in your root folder where your script is:

```
pip install backtrader -t .
```

Answer (score 0):

Found your answer  !pip install backtrader

Comment: OP wrote: _I installed backtrader on windows via cmd prompt like this: pip3 install backtrader_